Improve select batch processing of large table
I have a table that have millions (from 30mln to even 70mln) of rows inside:
create table customers {
 id uuid,
 customer_name text,
 -- more columns of various types,
 department_id uuid,
 row_number integer,
 status text,
 type text
}

And now I want to process them in batches will a following conditions:
select
 *
from
 customers
where
 department_id = :id
 and status in ('PROCESSED')
 and type in ('EXTERNAL', 'INTERNAL')
order_by
 id
offset 0 rows fetch first 5000 rows only

I query data through spring / hibernate.
Full data size that I want to process this way could be from only a hundred up to a million rows.
I tried different indexes like:

department_id
department_id, status, type
department_id, status, type, row_number

and modifying query to take a different approach:
:max_row_number we know from previous batch.
from
 customers
where
 department_id = :id
 and status in ('PROCESSED')
 and type in ('EXTERNAL', 'INTERNAL')
 and row_number > :max_row_number
order_by
 row_number 
limit 5000

But none of the improvements seems to work. Processing can take even an hour. For example altered query is hitting department_id only index. I run analyze but didn't helped either.
EDIT:
I refactored query to two use cases:
where
 department_id = :id
 and status in = 'PROCESSED'
 and type in ('EXTERNAL', 'INTERNAL')

and
where
 department_id = :id
 and type in ('EXTERNAL', 'INTERNAL')

It helped a little.

Using a cursor could improve performance since the query is executed just once. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/#getting-results-based-on-a-cursor

you have to see the plan, using EXPLAIN PLAN ANALYZE and make decision accordingly. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-explain/. Without seeing execution plan, we cannot make right decision.

@VenkataramanR The query will become slow because you have to execute it over and over again, skip the first X rows and then limit 5000. With 70 million records, you have to execute this query 14000 times... And each query it will be slower than the previous query.

@FrankHeikens, if the indexes are proper, the query should execute fine, even if we do it in batches. I suspect the indexes are not properly being used.

@VenkataramanR How can 14000 queries be faster than 1 query? Impossible.

Why 14000 queries? Sorry if I mislead you somehow, worst case scenario is 1_000_000 rows / 5_000 batch size = 200 queries. I could put explain output from pgAdmin of this exact query:
FROM CUSTOMERS SE1_0
WHERE SE1_0.DEPARTMENT_ID = '01905563-6898-8c63-3494-7833e061c0af'
 AND SE1_0.TYPE IN ('EXTERNAL', 'INTERNAL')
 AND SE1_0.STATUS IN ('PROCESSED')
ORDER BY SE1_0.ID
OFFSET 10000 ROWS FETCH FIRST 5000 ROWS ONLY;

but the bottom line is that optimizer used customers primary key to Index scan and it executed over an hours.

Why has the name of the column changed from id to row_number?

An index on (department_id, status, id) would likely help. Since "type" is tested for multiple values, putting it in the index ahead of "id" lowers the utility

Always put the columns based on selectivity. As the index is not highly selective, the optimizer goes for index scan. The index should be (id, department_id, status) to be more effective.

@FrankHeikens I finally managed to do some progress. After refactoring query and making sure that index is used I changed the implementation to JdbcTemplate.queryForStream() and this looks promising. For batching stuff I implemented Spliterator that gather objects into list, do some other porcessing stuff and emits Stream again. And with this combined approach I went down around ten times on local. Yet still I don't like how much memory this solution takes so need to fine tune it more.

@jjanes So in the second case I've tried to switch query approach from offset to limit. Since the id is type of UUID I couldn't calculate max(id) effectively so I just used integer row_number to order and skip already processed rows which also is unique within given department. Unfortunetly that didn;t helped.

"The index should be (id, department_id, status) to be more effective"  Since id is not even specified in the where clause, this will be almost entirely ineffective.  No matter how many of distinct values of id there are, it can't be selective if not used as the basis of selection.
